# SQLite3 : How to create db via code?

Tags: database, cocoa, sqlite

In my cocoa application, I am including a SQLite3 db. General process is:

1. I check if database with same name exists in Documents folder.
2. If it does not exist I copy it from application binary to Documents folder.

My question is:

> Can we directly create db via code, if
>   it does not exist.. something like
>   create db xyz ?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: I don't know exactly how the Cocoa SQLite API works, but in the C SQLite API, if the file doesn't not exist, it's created automatically by the sqlite3_open() function.

Comment: ok.. can you give some example statements... say if I have to create test_table then how can I create it using C?

Comment: Same with Adobe AIR. If there is no sqlite db then by opening a connection to a named file will create it.